# How to map third party IdP SAML attributes to my local application roles using keycloak-saml adapter

Tags: authentication, jboss, keycloak, saml, idp

My setup is:

- EAP 6.4.18
- keycloak-saml adapter
- Third party IdP server (not a keycloak server)

I'm trying to secure one of the web applications inside an EAR. Currently my standalone.xml looks like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-saml:1.3">
    <secure-deployment name="myapp.war">
        <SP entityID="https://mydomain/myapp/" sslPolicy="EXTERNAL" nameIDPolicyFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" logoutPage="/logout.jsp" forceAuthentication="false" isPassive="false" turnOffChangeSessionIdOnLogin="false">
            <Keys>
                <Key signing="true" encryption="false">
                    <KeyStore password="pass" file="/path-to/keyStore.jks">
                        <PrivateKey alias="sp" password="pass"/>
                        <Certificate alias="sp"/>
                    </KeyStore>
                </Key>
            </Keys>
            <IDP entityID="...entityID...">
                <SingleSignOnService signRequest="true" validateResponseSignature="true" requestBinding="POST" bindingUrl="...sso dinding..." assertionConsumerServiceUrl="https://mydomain/myapp/saml"/>
                <SingleLogoutService validateRequestSignature="true" validateResponseSignature="true" signRequest="true" signResponse="true" requestBinding="POST" responseBinding="POST" postBindingUrl="...slo binding..." redirectBindingUrl="...redirect..."/>
                <Keys>
                    <Key signing="true" encryption="false">
                        <KeyStore password="pass" file="/path-to/keyStore.jks">
                            <Certificate alias="idp"/>
                        </KeyStore>
                    </Key>
                </Keys>
            </IDP>
        </SP>
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
```

This part works just fine. I'm getting redirected to the IdP and I can login. The problem is that my application roles and the ones returned by the IdP do not match.

How can I configure a role mapping between those 2 so that the user has the correct roles in the session?

Ty.

Note:

I've done something like this with the picketlink subsystem. Below I used a properties file to do such mapping. I thought something similar could be done with the keycloak adapter, but the "keycloak-saml:1.1" schema doesn't seem to have a way to select a security-domain.

```
<security-domain name="my-realm">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.jboss.auth.SAML2LoginModule" flag="optional">
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    </login-module>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule" flag="optional">
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/rolesMapping-roles.properties"/>
        <module-option name="replaceRole" value="true"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
```

With the picketlink subsystem I could select my security domain and the roles mapping would happen.

```
<service-provider name="myapp.war" security-domain="my-realm"...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the configuration I was missing:

```
​<RoleMappingsProvider id="properties-based-role-mapper">
       ​<Property name="properties.file.location" value="/opt/mappers/roles.properties"/>
​</RoleMappingsProvider>
```

The implementation class of "properties-based-role-mapper" is: org.keycloak.adapters.saml.PropertiesBasedRoleMapper

More information here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_saml-general-config

The problem was that I was looking at schema version 1.1 which doesn't provide that option. The version 1.3 does, works perfectly.

I hope this question/answer helps someone out there.

Cheers.